# What values to be taken for x-axis and y-axis?

Tags: photosynthesis, data

I did a lab on form and function in photosynthesis and I recorded the values of absorption spectrum in spinach chlorophyll extract. I have the following data and I need to draw a graph. I didn't understand what I should take for x-axis and for y-axis. Can anyone please explain this.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to plot the slope, or are you also trying to do linear regression as well? The answer and sources that I give you depend on this.

Comment: @NabeehaChowdhury I need to draw a graph which describes, how many peaks does the absorption spectrum contain? and at what wavelength is the photosynthesis greatest? How does the color of an angiosperm leaf relate to the absorption spectrum you have generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter *really*, but for aesthetics sake, you'd plot the wavelength on x and the absorbance on y. We tend to visualize such data as spectral or absorbance as "peaks" on the range of interest. There's a fairly good example [here](https://www.philpoteducation.com/mod/book/tool/print/index.php?id=782&chapterid=1131). It has something to do with convention: traditionally 
 the independent variable on x and the dependent variable on y. There's a good answer on [cross-validated on the matter, too](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123938/how-to-determine-which-variable-goes-on-the-x-y-axes-in-a-scatterplot).